# Creating a Multiindex on a Dataframe to perform PanelOLS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

So I imagine that this problem is quite simple but I just cannot manage to find an answer. What I am trying to do is run an PanelOLS over stock data. To do this I import 2 tables, one with weekly returns on a stock and one with weekly search frequency on google trends and concat them into one ‘Main Dataframe’. Then I loop this operation x amount of times so that I have a number of different stocks in my ‘Main Dataframe’. This looks something like this:

```
             Open  Close Ticker  log(weekly returns)  Search Frequency
2016-01-09  34.84  28.04   ACAD                -0.22              25.0
2016-01-16  28.46  23.78   ACAD                -0.18              26.0
2016-01-09  24.49  24.52   ABBB                 0.00              24.0
2016-01-16  24.11  20.69   ABBB                -0.15              26.0
```

Now I need to create a multiindex over date and ticker in order to run the regression, but it does not sort it the way it should and as a result I get the error:

> NotImplementedError: Only 2-level MultiIndex are supported.

When I include:

```
for stock in stocklist:
    stock_detail_df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    trend_df = pd.read_csv(path2, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    complete_df = pd.concat([stock_detail_df, trend_df], axis=1)
    master_df = master_df.append(complete_df)

master_df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
master_df['Date'] = master_df['index']
master_df = master_df.drop(['index'], 1)
master_df.set_index(['Date', 'Ticker'], inplace=True)
```

all I get is:

```
                    Open  Close  log(weekly returns)  Search Frequency
Date       Ticker                                                     
2016-01-09 ACAD    34.84  28.04                -0.22              25.0
2016-01-16 ACAD    28.46  23.78                -0.18              26.0
2016-01-23 ACAD    24.49  24.52                 0.00              24.0
2016-01-30 ACAD    24.11  20.69                -0.15              26.0
```

The dataframe does not change/looks the same as before, although if I swap 'Date' and 'Ticker', it does create a multiindex which looks something like this, but this does not help me perform the regression (I have also tried to use index.swaplevel(0, 1) but that just returns the table above):

```
                    Open  Close  log(weekly returns)  Search Frequency
Ticker Date                                                           
ACAD   2016-01-09  34.84  28.04                -0.22              25.0
       2016-01-16  28.46  23.78                -0.18              26.0
       2016-01-23  24.49  24.52                 0.00              24.0
       2016-01-30  24.11  20.69                -0.15              26.0
```

In any case, the end-product should look as follows:

```
                    Open  Close  log(weekly returns)  Search Frequency
Date       Ticker                                                     
2016-01-09 ACAD    34.84  28.04                -0.22              25.0
           ABBB    10.21  11.05                -0.18              26.0
2016-01-16 ACAD    24.49  24.52                 0.00              24.0
           ABBB    11.05  15.07                -0.15              26.0
```

I will also post the complete code if I need to, but there is quite a lot that won't have anything to do with the problem and I did not want to include unnecessary code. And since I was able to create a multiindex (just the wrong order), I imagine that there is an easy solution that I am not seeing. I am using python 2.7 and pandas 18.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 4 entries, 2016-01-09 to 2016-01-16
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Open                   4 non-null float64
Close                  4 non-null float64
Ticker                 4 non-null object
log(weekly returns)    4 non-null float64
Search Frequency       4 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes

             Open  Close Ticker  log(weekly returns)  Search Frequency
2016-01-09  34.84  28.04   ACAD                -0.22                25
2016-01-16  28.46  23.78   ACAD                -0.18                26
2016-01-09  24.49  24.52   ABBB                 0.00                24
2016-01-16  24.11  20.69   ABBB                -0.15                26
```

Using

```
df.index.name='Date'
df.set_index('Ticker', append=True).sortlevel()
```

produces

```
                    Open  Close  log(weekly returns)  Search Frequency
Date       Ticker                                                     
2016-01-09 ABBB    24.49  24.52                 0.00                24
           ACAD    34.84  28.04                -0.22                25
2016-01-16 ABBB    24.11  20.69                -0.15                26
           ACAD    28.46  23.78                -0.18                26
```

Comment: This worked with the addition of inplace=True in the .set_index, thank you so much!

Comment: That's right, the above statement was for straight print out. Glad this was helpful!